# Can't find the file from views.py

Tags: python, django

I am stuck with a really weird problem.

I have a file called: "**test.txt**".

It is in the same directory with views.py. But I can't read it... **FileNotFoundError**.

But if I create **read_file.py** in the same directory with **views.py** and **test.txt**, it works absolutely fine.

What is wrong with views? Is this some sort of restriction by Django?

This code works on read_file, doesn't work on views.py:

```
fkey = open("test.txt", "rb")
key = fkey.read()
```

Comment: Research about working directory vs. directory where the source code is.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Could you be more specific please?

Comment: @user19497472 where the problem is persisting (`views.py`?) try running `print(os.getcwd())` and make sure `os` is imported. from here you will see where the cwd is, and you may need to build a `open_relative` function which I'll answer your question with

Comment: Checkout [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info) for  official documentation, free resources and more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem may be relative vs absolute file handling. Using the following Python snippet, you can work out where the interpreter's current working directory is:

```py
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

You should notice it's not in the same directory as the `views.py`, as `views.py` is likely being invoked/called from another module. You may choose to change all your `open` calls to include the whole path to these files, or use an implementation like this:

```py
import os

# This function can be used as a replacement for `open`
# which will allow you to access files from the file.
def open_relative(path, flag="r"):

    # This builds the relative path by joining the current directory
    # plus the current filename being executed.
    relative_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), path)

    return open(relative_path, flag) # return file handler
```

Then, this should work:

```py
fkey = open_relative("test.txt", "rb")
key = fkey.read()
```

Hope this helps!